# How can I randomly populate a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to produce an exploration game, so naturally I started with a world generator. I am stuck, however, on populating my list of biomes. The "biome_map" list is essentially an array that is equal in width and height to whatever size the user requested. Here is the code I have written:

```
EWbiome_map = [] #produces an empty row that is E_W_Size km wide
for chunk1 in range (1, (E_W_Size + 1)):
    EWbiome_map = EWbiome_map + ["empty"]

biome_map = []

for chunk2 in range (1, (N_S_Size + 1)):
    biome_map = biome_map + [EWbiome_map]
print ("Map Initialized")
print ("Assigning Biomes...") # produces an empty array
print (biome_map)

Seed1 = Seed
random.seed (Seed)
x = 0   
for element in biome_map:
    y = 0
    for chunk3 in element:
        (biome_map[x])[y] = random.choice (biome_list)
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
print ("Biomes Assigned")
print (biome_map)
```

The error shows up in the result, where each list is a copy of the last.

```
Modules Successfully Imported
Biomes Initialized
Map Initialized
Assigning Biomes...
[['empty', 'empty', 'empty'], ['empty', 'empty', 'empty'],['empty', 'empty', 'empty']]
Biomes Assigned
[['tundra', 'tundra', 'plateaus'], ['tundra', 'tundra', 'plateaus'], ['tundra', 'tundra', 'plateaus']]
```

Comment: For the love of Guido, don't put spaces between your function name and the call parentheses: `print('hi')` instead of `print ('hi')`

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ no, but it is an issue of [style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
biome_map = biome_map + [EWbiome_map]
```

You are making `biome_map` to be a list where each element is the list `EWbiome_map`. Note that each element is not a *copy* of the list, it is the list itself. To correct this you want a *copy* of the `EWbiome_map` list. One way to do this is

```
biome_map = biome_map + [list(EWbiome_map)]
```

Another way is

```
biome_map = biome_map + [EWbiome_map[:]]
```

There are also other ways, but these should be clear enough.

---

To clarify what is happening in your code, remember that everything in Python is an object, and an object is handled internally as a pointer to where the data in the object is stored. When you add `EWbiome_map` to your `biome_map` list, that list actually stores a pointer to `EWbiome_map` and not the data itself. So when you change one occurrence of that data it is changed for all references everywhere.

Doing copies by `list(EWbiome_map)` or `EWbiome_map[:]` makes a new list with its own data and pointer. Now you can change one of those without affecting the others.

**TL;DR** Variables are handled differently in Python than in many other languages, since everything is an object. Pointers are used more extensively than you think, but the implementation is (usually) hidden from you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a reference to the same list `EWbiome_map` when creating `biome_map`. Instead do something like:

```
biome_map = [['empty']*E_W_Size]*N_S_Size
```

Your entire code could however be pretty much shortened to:

```
biome_map = [[random.choice(biome_list) for _ in range(E_W_Size)]
             for _ in range(N_S_Size)]
```

Comment: Why would you use `range(1,E_W_Size +1)` instead of `range(E_W_Size)` if you don't use the value, as both will spawn `E_W_Size` elements ?

Comment: you are right, I just copied from the question. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, you are referencing the same EWbiome_map each time, which causes you to alter it in all rows of biome_map.

However, your code also does a lot of unnecessary things, like initializing an empty map and iterating with 'chunk3' and 'element' instead of just using x and y directly.

Faster would be to use numpy and replace **all** of that code with:

```
import numpy as np
biome_map = np.random.choice(biome_list,size=(N_S_Size,E_W_Size))
```